# Exclude a particular character from being generated by random.choice()

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, random

I am trying to generate random characters using random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase). I do not want to include all the lowercase characters in the random.choice(). I want to exclude some

```
import random 
import string

random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
```

choice to select from 
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
exclude 
'abd' from the choice generated by the random function

Comment: Why not explicitly write the letters you want yourself?

Comment: Replace `string.ascii_lowercase` by a string containing only the characters you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
import random 
import string

unwanted_chars = 'abd'
random.choice([s for s in string.ascii_lowercase if s not in unwanted_chars])
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. This answers my question

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all a,b,d characters by replacing them with an empty string:

```
import re

s = re.sub('[abd]', '', string.ascii_lowercase)
```